# Nodejs Netsuite restless Error : (node:1128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: node.js, netsuite

I am using nodejs npm module netsuite-rest to connect to netsuite rest web services and I am getting this error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch bloc

```
let NetSuiteRestlet = require('netsuite-restlet');
const config = {
account: 'XXXXX',
username: 'XXXXX',
password: 'XXXX',
role: 'FOM PH Sales Manager'
};

 const url = 'https://6218235.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com';
  const parameters = {
 internalid: 1054
};

 let ns = new NetSuiteRestlet(config);
   // Example using the get function
  ns.get(parameters, url).then((out) => { console.log(out) });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `get` request is failing, but is not being handled correctly.

Since you are using promises, you would simply chain on a `.catch` after the `.then` to catch the promise rejection.

For example:

```js
ns.get(parameters, URL)
.then((out) => { console.log(out) })
.catch((error) => { 
   console.log(error) // and/or handle the error some other way
}
```

See here for more:

1. How to handle promise rejections: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-promises-rejection/